# TFS Web create my own theme

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, themes, skin

How can i create new design for tfs? 
I am looking for any guide or tutorial.

I am looking to change layout colors etc..
so i am able to go to profile ,options, theme and select MyNewShinyTheme.
Thank you for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

browsing to the location of installed tfs i have been able to modify the theme.

Answer (score 0):

This is a one-stop-shop for answering your complete question (assuming you have SharePoint 2010 deployed as part of your TFS system):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/02/03/working-with-sharepoint-2010-themes.aspx